# Reading a string from user

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I press the enter key after giving input for t, the program terminates as string takes the newline character as input. What can I do? I cannot output something between these two inputs and an enter after t is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you press to end the input for `t` is added to the input buffer. So the first input in the buffer seen by `getline` is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and it thinks you have given an empty line.

Use the [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function to skip past the newline:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You can also use two `std::getline` calls, and use e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the input an `int`. Or put in an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and extract using the normal `>>` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `getline(cin, s)` twice. Fist will ignore rest of first line and the second will actually read what you need or better use [`cin.ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) with appropriate arguments